# how keys for viewstate decryption is shared with the client?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, viewstate

I've just started to read about `viewstate` in `asp.net`. I know it is serialized data encoded with base64 and I know it can also be encrypted using a key[which is Auto-generated every time if we don't change the default in `web.config` in case of server farm or etc.]
but my problem is that how this key is shared with the client [so that the client could read it] that ensures the safety of data?
does it have to do anything with HTTPS protocols and shared keys or they are completely something else?
if it is something else, so how the keys are transferred throw the web?

Comment: What makes you the that the client decrypts the data at all?

Comment: Thank you Mason for your comment, well as I was searching for my answer, I have been faced with this idea that client does decrypt the value, but I had some problems with it: first if it is not suppose to be decrypted by the client, why we don't hash the data to be sure it's not reversible. Second I sought decryption is as an additional security level on the base64, because it can be easily decoded. So in this way our -maybe sensitive- data will be a little more secure.

Comment: The client does not need to read the ViewState data. ViewState merely is sent to the client and included with subsequent posts so that Web Forms can maintain state (because the web is [stateless](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/what-is-stateless-stateful-models-web-development/) by default). It's base64 encoded, but that's not at all for security. Base64 is easily reversible. Even though ViewState is further encrypted, you should not put *any* data into it that you do not want the client to have access to.

Comment: On top of all that....why are you learning Web Forms?! Web Forms is a dying/dead framework. If you're going to exert your time and energy, put it towards something valuable like ASP.NET Core MVC, or Blazor, or Angular/Vue/React.